# Noun phrases without participles as absolutes: behind those high twigs, their leaves leathery green on top

Tags: parsing, noun-phrases, absolute-construction

> My earliest childhood memory is of the swaying limbs of Golden
>   Delicious apple trees. Rows of them stood next to a dirt road that
>   separated our orchard from the front yard.
>
> *The Kentucky summer sky hung hot behind those high twigs*, ***their leaves leathery green on top***, **soft as down underneath**.

Frank Browning,“Sweet Temptation,” Reader’s Digest

The word in the *sentence* is: high **twigs**

The effective word in the ***phrase*** is: their **leaves**

I think the phrase, without a participle, is still absolute. Do you agree?

Comment: In both cases, being is omitted, which is usual for absolute phrases.

Comment: Yes, it's the verbless analogue of "their leaves being leathery green on top, soft as down underneath". The clause is functioning as a supplementary adjunct. Note, though, that it is a clause, not a phrase.

Comment: Weird, that the sky is **behind** not **above**.

Comment: @BillJ add your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute phrases can omit the verb, especially where it is *to be*. The verb is then implicit. Putting the omitted, implicit verb back into that absolute phrase gets you:

> "their leaves **being** leathers green on top, soft as down underneath"

Comment: This answer contains no new information compared to the comments, but adding it here as an answer may allow it stop being categorised as 'unanswered'.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of participle?

Comment: Participles are verb forms used in forming different verb *aspects*. English has two sorts of participle, past participle (for the *perfect aspect*) and the progressive participle, also known as the present participle or continuous participle (for the *progressive aspect*). For regular verbs, the past participle is generally formed with *-ed* and the progressive participle with *-ing*. "I have shower*ed*", "I am talk*ing*".